# How to handle on click on push notifications ios

Tags: ios, push-notification

I managed to recive a push notification, but i don't know how to handle the click on the push notification that arrive to the application, i want to tell the application when click go to specific activity based on the type of notification, not just open the app (Default behavior)

i know that i can receive

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

    NSLog(@"Here I should Recive The notification .... ") ;
    //call the commented functions .....
}
```

in this function , but when i implement it, the notification don't appear and just do what in this function

Answer (score 3):

For anyone struggle with this at 2022, Here's a working solution. You need to implement the didReceive function inside AppDelegate after connecting your push notification services and than get the notification content:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    let title = response.notification.request.content.title
    let message = response.notification.request.content.body
    userDefaultsManager.savePushNotificationData(pushNotificationData: ["title" : title, "message" : message])
}
```

note that in case you need to get custom data inside the push itself it will be store inside the userInfo.
You can get it like that:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
     let url = userInfo["url"]
}
```

Comment: How to give the url which you retrieved from `userInfo` to the AppDelegate? Or what are you gonna do with the url?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but in case you need that parameter anywhere else in your app you can save it to UserDefaults or pass it to a Singleton class. I Hope that this is what you meant

Comment: I found a solution: the `url` can be given to a `NSNotification` in the `userInfo` parameter. then you can post this notification (you have to register it beforehand), it will be fired then you can to some custom behaviour in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle this the click as shown in code,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

//Accept push notification when the app is not open.
        if (remoteNotifiInfo) {
            [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotifiInfo];
        }

}



   // On click of notification open related screen.
```

override didReceiveRemoteNotification like this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        {
                    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
                    if ( state == UIApplicationStateInactive )
                    {
                        //Your actions on notification click
                        double delayInSeconds = 0.3;
                        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
                        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                            //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
                            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushTOEventDetails" object:eventVO];
                        });

                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate some specific ViewController by tapping pushnotification Just add ViewController navigation code in didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

NSLog(@"Here I should Receive The notification .... ") ;
//call the commented functions .....

FirstController *firstviewcontroller = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushviewcontroller:firstviewcontroller animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: but this will done once i receive the notification, and the notification won't appear in the device , i want the default behavior that the notification appear in the device and when i tap on it i can do something ..

Comment: first please be specific about what you want to do

Comment: without this function i can receive a notification, i just want to "on click on the notification do something" where to put this code

Answer (score 0):

That delegate method will only get fired if the application is active. If the application is not running, you should get the notification payload using `launchOptions` in the delegate method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and do navigation according to the payload.

Comment: thanks for your reply :) , i know this but all of this will happen automatically , i just want to handle the on click on notification to do specific behavior not just opening the application

Comment: Oh i get it, you want to add a notification to Notification Center. You can do it adding an immediate `UILocalNotification` when you receive a remote notification when your application is active.

Comment: how to implement this ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html