# Unable to act on notification after app is killed

Tags: objective-c, background, push-notification, notifications, ios10

When my app is in foreground or inactive then upon receiving push notification, I can click on it and the desired action occurs. If I kill the app then upon tapping a notification the app comes to the home screen. [Handling Push Notifications when App is Terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058870/handling-push-notifications-when-app-is-terminated) from this post I understood that this is the desired behavior.

I also have 2 actionable buttons attached on my notification. if I click on one of them then I am not redirected to the home screen and the app loads indefinitely! Is there a work around to make the user come to the home screen?

Methods implemented by me which dont get executed after the app is killed and i receive a notification

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler

(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler

(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Also, I read on the posts that after the app is killed and if I click on a notification then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is executed. I added logger statement in my method but i dont receive them.
Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: It will be tough for you to get help with this without revealing some code.

Comment: Whenever I killed the app, my xcode was getting disconnected so couldn't identify if the methods were getting executed!

Comment: in iOS 10 with usernotification,if the app is killed and tapping on notificaton in addition to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions didReceiveNotificationResponse method also triggerd.So u dont need to implement notification action logic in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.