# Can I handle a "Silent notification" when app is terminated in objective.c?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I want to handle "Silent" notifications, when app is in foreground or in background it work's fine, but not when app is terminated. Can You help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO.**

You can't handle it. Reason is when application is in terminated state, you can't access resource of it. iOS don't allows you to do same. Refer this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Also read this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058870/handling-push-notifications-when-app-is-terminated) post for some better understanding.

Comment: Thanks so much @Pushkraj